# If and how to use the Composite pattern (GoF's)

Tags: java, design-patterns, interpreter, composite, ebnf

I should create a mini command interpreter (System.in) in Java to support manipulation of graphic object using appropriate GoF's patterns. The interpreter's grammar is a simple EBNF language like this:
`

```
<cmd>::=<create>|<remove>|<move>|<scale>|<list>|<group>|<ungroup>|<area>|<perimeter>
<create>::= new <typeconstr> <pos>
<remove>::= del <objID>
<move>::= mv <objID> <pos> | mvoff <objID> <pos> 
<scale>::= scale <objID> <posfloat>
<list>::= ls <objID>| ls <type> | ls all | ls groups
<group>::= grp <listID>
<ungroup>::= ungrp <objID>
<area>::= area <objID>| area <type> | area all
<perimeter>::= perimeter <objID>| perimeter <type> | perimeter all
<pos>::=( <posfloat> , <posfloat> )
<typeconstr>::= circle (<posfloat>) | rectangle <pos> | img (<path>)
<type>::= circle | rectangle | img
<listID>::= <objID> { , <objID> }
```

The commands' behavior is managed by the Command pattern and it's ok.

I thought to use the Composite pattern for the structure of a general command in the easiest way, but I found it to be a difficult task. Any advise?

Is only the Interpreter pattern a good choice to do this instead? Or a combination of both?

Once I have the Composite structure I thought to use a Builder with it (maybe a Recursive Builder) to create the command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Composite is a great pattern for representing tree structures, but I don't think that's a good fit for what you're doing here.  Your commands aren't deeply nested, and there's no recursive nesting, so you probably wouldn't get much benefit from this structure.

Your commands are structured so that the first token determines the action, and there are command-specific rules for parsing the rest of the string.  A command pattern looks ideal, and I'd suggest using a factory pattern to encapsulate the specific implementations:

```
public class MyCommand{
    public static MyCommand getInstance(String str){
        String commandType = // get first token
        String args = // remainder of string

        switch (commandType){
            case "new":
                return buildCreateCommand(args);
            // ... other cases
        }
    }

    private MyCreateCommand buildCreateCommand(String args){
        // Construct create command from args
    }
}

class MyCreateCommand extends MyCommand{
    // Create command things
}
```

Comment: HI , I dont understand the advantages of your factory solution . Compared to GoF's Factory Method pattern  you don't have the factory hierarchy . What are the benefits?

Comment: The big benefit of the Factory pattern is that the method can choose which subclass to instantiate, and the precise type is not exposed to the caller.  In this case, `getInstance` inspects the command string and decides based on the first token which type of command it is.  This means you can add new commands without altering the client, can alter how each command is identified in just one place, and you can alter the syntax of each command independently.

Comment: I'd really stress too, your combo of Composite, Interpreter and Builder sounds like a very good way to attack the general case problem of EBNF lanuage parsing, but if you want to do that you'd do well to look into Antlr before you build your own: http://www.antlr.org/